# Where facebook saves an infomation about registered users?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate my site with FB. So I have begun with registration plugin. My question is: where FB is saving the registered data, because when I am already registered on my site via FB registration plugin and viewing registration form again FB informs me that I am already registered. I could not find any information about it in user profile or in my app panel.

Thx for advise. If something is not clear I will be glad to explain my problem once again.

Comment: LOL, at first glance i thought you were with FBI and trying to investigate facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `signed_request` that Facebook is sending to your app via the `redirect_uri` (which is a page somewhere within your Site URL). It will have the encoded information for that user.

Comment: Will check that, but it contains information about one user which is registered on my site? I want information about all users which have registered on my site via Facebook :)

Comment: You will get all registered information, when you store it in your own database as recommended by Facebook for the registration plugin.  If you didn't store that information, I would suggest creating a new facebook app id so every user has to re-authenticate so you can start collecting that info properly.  Happy coding!

Comment: OK, but although I did not, FB did and I am asking where it stores those information?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "integrate my site with FB", I assume you mean "let people authenticate on my site by authenticating on Facebook ?".

I think there is all the info there :

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

EDIT : regarding the "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/" example ; I can not say it authoritavely since I don't have the code, but I think what happens is that :

- The registration form is in a iframe, showing a page that is generated on the server side (maybe, *your* server)
- If you are not logged in, the form is not filled
- There is a "login with facebook" that opens a pop-up with a page (from Facebook site) that has an extra param called "redirect-url" ; this will be a url or *your* site
- When the user enters it's credentials, on the registration form that is posted to Facebook, they check the username/password, and when done, they call the "redirect-url" (again, a URL from *your* site) and pass the info in this (in this case, the redirect is configured to get a number of fields (name, birthday, location, etc...)
- Your site gets the info in the form of a "signed_request" (see the section "Reading the Data"). In this case, it will render the same "Registration" page, except I would guess  that on the server-side, some fields have been filled with the info provided by FB's signed_request.

The trick is that in this example, everything happens in an iframe - I'm not sure how this is mandatory.

Now, about the question "If I am already logged in FB, and I go to the Registration form, how does my info get in the form ?", I can only suppose that FB sets a number of cookies when you log in, that client site can use - but I agree with you that the documentation is not extremely clear about that. Probably, it's suppose to be hidden by FB's API, but the doc does clearly point to which one (at least on this page).

Again, I'm just speculating from the doc and tinkering with the requests made on the pages (and experience with similar oauth-y authentication schemes) ; hopefully someone with an actual application can give you more info.

Hoping this helped - sorry if it did not. Good luck with your dev.

PH

Comment: I meant rather register. And then how can I know who is registered and where those information are saved?

Comment: It depends on whay you mean by "who is registered". Normally, after the user has logged on Facebook, they are redirected to a url of *your* site with an "access_token" in the URL, The "access token" is generated by FB, and somehow "represents" the logged user. You can use it against Facebook APIs to get information about the user (see "Using the access token"). Depending on what the facebook graph api provides, you might get all the info you need - I guess you can easily get the email, etc...

Comment: You don`t understand me. Look here please: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/. Then register yourself to the example app. Try do open this link once again and then it will show you face and tell 'You have registered.'. How (from where) does the app know about it?